# Flutter SingleChildScrollView stop scrolling when LIMIT reached

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering when using `SingleChildScrollView`, is there a way to stop scrolling either up or down when for example the page is already at the top, so I would like to prevent the page from keep scrolling up for example. Because I don't want to change the background of the entire `Scaffold` but when scrolling above the top, there's the white `Scaffold` background color showing, and it does not look that great. Thank you! The code is not something too fancy, eg.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 2000,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
);
```

[This is what what it shows when keep scrolling up when already at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12k65.png)

Comment: I would help if you can show your code.

Comment: @peacetype I submitted a simple example of what I am basically trying to do. I would appreciate it a lot if u could help me! :)

Comment: @AlejandroJimenez so is your question how to disable or enable scroll of your SingleChildScrollView programmatically?

Comment: @Henok, what I am trying to do is to leave the scroll enabled, but when the page is at the top, is to prevent the page from keep scrolling up, making the Scaffold background show behind (happens only on iOS I think)

Comment: @AlejandroJimenez then can you please share a link of your image on what your top space when you want to stop scrolling or what keeping to scroll up causes, helps to clarify the issue

Comment: @Henok, ok I already shared a screenshot of what it looks like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `ClampingScrollPhysics()` to your **SingleChildScrollView** will do the trick,

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  physics : ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 2000,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
);
```